# Problems in integrating my android app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

I am developing Splash screen,`GridView`, `ListView` and 4 other codes.

Since every item click in `GridView` namely Image,video,document and upload displays the same items in `ListView`(my code is like that) I am confused as to how to apply the loops in the **onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id)** method so that i can display image code,video code,document code and uploading code in accordance with the items in `GridView` and `ListView`

**To be very precise just go through the flow below**

1.Image(Grid View)-----Onclick---->Item1(listview)--Onclick()-->Image Code

```
                          ---->Item2(listview)--Onclick()-->Image Code
                          ---->Item3(listview)--Onclick()-->Image Code
                          ---->Item4(listview)--Onclick()-->Image Code
```

2.Video(Grid View)-----Onclick---->Item1(listview)--Onclick()-->Video Code

```
                          ---->Item2(listview)--Onclick()-->Video Code
                          ---->Item3(listview)--Onclick()-->Video Code
                          ---->Item4(listview)--Onclick()-->Video Code
```

3.Document(Grid View)-----Onclick---->Item1(listview)--Onclick()-->Document Code

```
                          ---->Item2(listview)--Onclick()-->Document Code
                          ---->Item3(listview)--Onclick()-->Document Code
                          ---->Item4(listview)--Onclick()-->DocumentCode
```

4.Upload(Grid View)-----Onclick---->Item1(listview)--Onclick()-->Upload Code

```
                          ---->Item2(listview)--Onclick()-->Upload Code
                          ---->Item3(listview)--Onclick()-->Upload Code
                          ---->Item4(listview)--Onclick()-->UploadCode
```

Thanks in advance if anybody could help it would be fantastic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your grid screen and list screen are seperate activities, then you can pass the "type" of the grid option that was selected by the user as an extra in the intent you are using to start the list activity. And then depending on this value, you can decide the action that is to be taken in the onItemClick.
Hope that helps.

1. Define the types for your operations. like,

   public static final int OPTION_IMAGECODE = 1 ;

   public static final int OPTION_VIDEOCODE = 2 ; ...etc

   and a varaible to hold the type like, private int selectedGridOption ;
2. When user clicks on the grid option, populate the variable. Like,

   selectedGridOption = OPTION_IMAGECODE ;  if the user selectes the image type.
3. In your intent you use to start the list activity put this value as an extra. Like,
   listActivityIntent.putExtra("Selected Option", selectedGridOption) ;
4. In you list activity you can retreive this value as,

   getIntent().getIntExtra("Selected Option", *default_value_you_want*) ;

Comment: Thanks for the ans !!can u give me an example, are you taking about putextra!!! if s can u give me an example

Comment: @ChetanS, I have edited my answer for you. Please see if that works for you.